# How can I find the location of a node using the GUI?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Very simple question: how can I find the location of a node in a node tree using the GUI? If it's impossible, how can I do it using Python?

If it makes any difference, I'm using Cycles.

Comment: try to organize your nodes with frames or groups

Comment: @Bithur Not sure what you're saying. I'm working on a script, and I just want to get an idea of scale and location in the node tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In GUI you will find this info in *Outliner* in *Datablocks view* under:

BlendfileData > Materials > *name_of_material* > NodeTree > ShaderNodetree > Nodes > *name_of_node* > Location

[image]

You can also keyframe such value or even drive it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this isn't possible through the GUI, however it is possible with python:

```
bpy.data.materials['Material Name'].node_tree.nodes['Node Name'].location[0]
```

Where `location[0]` gives the X and `location[1]` gives the Y.

[image]

Comment: You can also use `location.x` and `location.y` (this works for any location vector in blender)